# C++: Is a mutex with `std::lock_guard` enough to synchronize two `std::thread`s?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

My question is based on below sample of C++ code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class ClassUtility
{
public:
    ClassUtility() {}
    ~ClassUtility() {}

    void do_something() {
      std::cout << "do something called" << std::endl;

      using namespace std::chrono_literals;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
};


int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {

  ClassUtility g_common_object;

  std::mutex  g_mutex;

  std::thread worker_thread_1([&](){

      std::cout << "worker_thread_1 started" << std::endl;

      for (;;) {

          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);

          std::cout << "worker_thread_1 looping" << std::endl;
          g_common_object.do_something();
      }
  });


  std::thread worker_thread_2([&](){

      std::cout << "worker_thread_2 started" << std::endl;

      for (;;) {

          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);

          std::cout << "worker_thread_2 looping" << std::endl;
          g_common_object.do_something();
      }
  });


  worker_thread_1.join();
  worker_thread_2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

This is more of a question to get my understanding clear rather & get a sample usage of `std::condition_variable` iff required.

I have 2 C++ `std::thread`s which start up in `main` method. Its a console app on `osx`. So compiling it using clang. Both the threads use a common object of
`ClassUtility` to call a method do some heavy task. For this sample code to explain the situation, both the threads run an infinite loop & close down only when 
the app closes i.e. when I press `ctrl+c` on the console.

**Seek to know:**

Is it correct if I jus use a `std::lock_guard` on `std::mutex` to synchronize or protect the calls made to the `common_obejct` of `ClassUtility`. Somehow, I seem
to be getting into trouble with this "*just a mutex approach*". None of the threads start if I lock gaurd the loops using mutex. Moreover, I get segfaults sometimes. Is this because they are lambdas ?
assigned to each thread ?

Is it better to use a `std::condition_variable` between the 2 threads or lambdas to signal & synchronize them ? If yes, then how would the `std::condition_variable` be used
here between the lambdas ?

**Note:** As the question is only to seek information, hence the code provided here might not compile. It is just to provide a real scenario

Comment: This should work just fine. How do you know that "none of the threads start?" Can you test it via something independent of shared state (such as by each thread writing to its own file instead of sharing `std::cout`)?

Comment: Also, note that you're leaving very little room for parallelism (or even thread switching) here, since the mutex remains locked for the duration of the sleeps.

Comment: If you have code where you get deadlock or starvation or segfaults, why on earth do you post simplified code that doesn't?

Comment: @Angew I have put the `cout`s which prove that my thread methods are getting blocked

Comment: As I mentioned, `std::cout` is a shared resource. Can you verify the threads's start using per-thread means only?

Comment: Works for me. Output: `worker_thread_1 started - worker_thread_2 started - worker_thread_1 looping - do something called - worker_thread_1 looping -
do something called` etc. Try also putting a `cout` _before_ you create the threads, just to be sure something else isn't swallowing the output and/or that you're running the same program you're compiling etc.

Comment: ok. as hinted in the answer as well, the actual code that I am trying has to wait for one thread loop to run & signal because my real code is not as simple as this. hence I need to the condition_variable. but as I said this question is posted to get my know-how & understanding around this correct. hence tried to simplify the situation to attract more suggestions.

Comment: POST COMPILING CODE THAT EXPERIENCES THE DESCRIBED PROBLEM.  This isn't hard, and not doing so risks your question being useless and a waste of time for people answering.  Define what it means for "nit work", and BE SPECIFIC. See [mcve].

Comment: as I have quoted in the question. this is not a question to get a code solution for a problem. it is strictly to clarify whether I need a condition_variable or not which is duly clarified in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Your code is safe

Remember, the lock_guard just calls `.lock()` and injects call to `.unlock()` to the end of the block. So

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    std::cout << "worker_thread_1 looping" << std::endl;
    g_common_object.do_something();
}
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
{ 
    g_mutex.lock();
    std::cout << "worker_thread_1 looping" << std::endl;
    g_common_object.do_something();
    g_mutex.unlock();
}
```

except:

1. the unlock is called even if the block is left via exception and
2. it ensures you won't forget to call it.

## Your code is not parallel

You are mutually excluding all of the loop body in each thread. There is nothing left that both threads could be actually doing in parallel. The main point of using threads is when each can work on separate set of objects (and only read common objects), so they don't have to be locked.

In the example code, you really should be locking *only* the work on common object; `std::cout` is thread-safe on it's own. So:

```
{ 
    std::cout << "worker_thread_1 looping" << std::endl;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
        g_common_object.do_something();
        // unlocks here, because lock_guard injects unlock at the end of innermost scope.
    }
}
```

I suppose the actual code you are trying to write does have something to actually do in parallel; just a thing to keep in mind.

## Condition variables are not needed

Condition variables are for when you need one thread to wait until another thread does some specific thing. Here you are just making sure the two threads are not modifying the object at the same time and for that `mutex` is sufficient and appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never terminates other than that I can't fault it.

As others point out it offers almost not opportunity for parallelism because of the long sleep that takes place with the mutex locked to sleeping thread.

Here's a simple version that terminates by putting arbitrary finite limits on the loops.

Is it maybe that you haven't understood what `join()` does?
It the current thread (executing `join()`) until the joined thread ends. But if it doesn't end neither does the current thread.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class ClassUtility
{
public:
    ClassUtility() {}
    ~ClassUtility() {}

    void do_something() {
      std::cout << "do something called" << std::endl;

      using namespace std::chrono_literals;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
};


int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {

  ClassUtility g_common_object;

  std::mutex  g_mutex;

  std::thread worker_thread_1([&](){

      std::cout << "worker_thread_1 started" << std::endl;

      for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {

          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);

          std::cout << "worker_thread_1 looping " << i << std::endl;
          g_common_object.do_something();
      }
  });


  std::thread worker_thread_2([&](){

      std::cout << "worker_thread_2 started" << std::endl;

      for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {

          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);

          std::cout << "worker_thread_2 looping " << i << std::endl;
          g_common_object.do_something();
      }
  });


  worker_thread_1.join();
  worker_thread_2.join();

  return 0;
}
```